# Inflating 5 linear layouts in scrollview overwriting each other

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-scrollview

I am currently working on a time table app with 5 days. My idea to do this was to place 5 linear layouts in a relative layout and the relative layout in a scroll view as it would not fit on the screen.

**I made my xml:**

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="schouten.jamie.maantje.com.roosternotifierfriesepoort.Activities.RoosterActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/maandag"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/dinsdag"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/woensdag"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/donderdag"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/vrijdag"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

**After that i started writing the code:**

```
for (int i = 0; i < maandag.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject maandagJSONObject = maandag.getJSONObject(i);

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            LinearLayout main =(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.maandag);

            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.roosteruur, main, false);

            TextView leerkracht = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.leerkracht);
            TextView les = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.vak);
            TextView lokaal = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.lokaal);
            TextView uur = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.uur);

            uur.setText(String.valueOf(i + 1)+")");
            lokaal.setText(maandagJSONObject.getString("lokaal"));
            les.setText(maandagJSONObject.getString("les"));
            leerkracht.setText(maandagJSONObject.getString("leraar"));

            Log.v("roosterp", maandagJSONObject.getString("les"));

            main.addView(view);

}
```

Ran it and it worked great so i thought copy and paste that 4 more times and change the days and done!

**So i did just that:**

```
public void parseJSON(String json){
    Log.v("JPARSER","parseJSON start");
    try {
        JSONObject objects = new JSONObject(json);

        JSONArray maandag = objects.getJSONArray("maandag");
        JSONArray dinsdag = objects.getJSONArray("dinsdag");
        JSONArray woensdag = objects.getJSONArray("woensdag");
        JSONArray donderdag = objects.getJSONArray("donderdag");
        JSONArray vrijdag = objects.getJSONArray("vrijdag");



        for (int i = 0; i < maandag.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject maandagJSONObject = maandag.getJSONObject(i);

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            LinearLayout main =(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.maandag);

            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.roosteruur, main, false);

            TextView leerkracht = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.leerkracht);
            TextView les = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.vak);
            TextView lokaal = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.lokaal);
            TextView uur = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.uur);

            uur.setText(String.valueOf(i + 1)+")");
            lokaal.setText(maandagJSONObject.getString("lokaal"));
            les.setText(maandagJSONObject.getString("les"));
            leerkracht.setText(maandagJSONObject.getString("leraar"));

            Log.v("roosterp", maandagJSONObject.getString("les"));

            main.addView(view);

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < dinsdag.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject dinsdagJSONObject = dinsdag.getJSONObject(i);

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            LinearLayout main =(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.maandag);

            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.roosteruur, main, false);

            TextView leerkracht = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.leerkracht);
            TextView les = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.vak);
            TextView lokaal = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.lokaal);
            TextView uur = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.uur);

            uur.setText(String.valueOf(i + 1)+")");
            lokaal.setText(dinsdagJSONObject.getString("lokaal"));
            les.setText(dinsdagJSONObject.getString("les"));
            leerkracht.setText(dinsdagJSONObject.getString("leraar"));
            Log.v("roosterp", dinsdagJSONObject.getString("les"));

            main.addView(view);

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < woensdag.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject woensdagJSONObject = woensdag.getJSONObject(i);

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            LinearLayout main =(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.maandag);

            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.roosteruur, main, false);

            TextView leerkracht = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.leerkracht);
            TextView les = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.vak);
            TextView lokaal = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.lokaal);
            TextView uur = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.uur);

            uur.setText(String.valueOf(i + 1)+")");
            lokaal.setText(woensdagJSONObject.getString("lokaal"));
            les.setText(woensdagJSONObject.getString("les"));
            leerkracht.setText(woensdagJSONObject.getString("leraar"));
            Log.v("roosterp", woensdagJSONObject.getString("les"));

            main.addView(view);

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < donderdag.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject donderdagJSONObject = donderdag.getJSONObject(i);

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            LinearLayout main =(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.maandag);

            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.roosteruur, main, false);

            TextView leerkracht = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.leerkracht);
            TextView les = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.vak);
            TextView lokaal = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.lokaal);
            TextView uur = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.uur);

            uur.setText(String.valueOf(i + 1)+")");
            lokaal.setText(donderdagJSONObject.getString("lokaal"));
            les.setText(donderdagJSONObject.getString("les"));
            leerkracht.setText(donderdagJSONObject.getString("leraar"));
            Log.v("roosterp", donderdagJSONObject.getString("les"));

            main.addView(view);

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < vrijdag.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject vrijdagJSONObject = vrijdag.getJSONObject(i);

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            LinearLayout main =(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.maandag);

            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.roosteruur, main, false);

            TextView leerkracht = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.leerkracht);
            TextView les = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.vak);
            TextView lokaal = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.lokaal);
            TextView uur = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.uur);

            uur.setText(String.valueOf(i + 1)+")");
            lokaal.setText(vrijdagJSONObject.getString("lokaal"));
            les.setText(vrijdagJSONObject.getString("les"));
            leerkracht.setText(vrijdagJSONObject.getString("leraar"));
            Log.v("roosterp", vrijdagJSONObject.getString("les"));

            main.addView(view);

        }


    }
    catch (JSONException e){
        Log.v("JPARSER","WUT? " + e);
    }


 }
```

But the result was not wat i was expecting instead of 5 nice little linear layouts i got wat looks like 1 just mixed with the data of a couple days so i guess there is something that is being overwritten somewhere but can't find where.

Comment: Try replacing your RelativeLayout with LinearLayout and set its orientation vertical.

Comment: @HusseinElFeky That did the trick! thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing your RelativeLayout with LinearLayout and set its orientation to vertical.

LinearLayout will arrange your views automatically, but if you want to use a RelativeLayout, then you will have to add `android:layout_below` attribute to each view you have inside that RelativeLayout. So LinearLayout is obviously more simple.